# Spring Data - write derived query to select by field value length

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Is it possible to write a Spring Data derived query to select by field value length?
For example `findByFieldLengthLessThan`?

I would like to select all records where field has a value which length has less than N characters.

Comment: You can try to use something like this repo.findByAndSort("targaryen", JpaSort.unsafe("LENGTH(firstname)<n")); check the documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do custom query this way,

@Query("select *from tableName where length(columnName)<=4")

Comment: I am aware of that, but I would like to use derived query if possible.

Comment: I guess you cannot do that way, one more option is findAll() and filter the result according to your requirement